# JSEncrypt encrypt on client and decrypt on server

Tags: encryption, certificate, javascript

I am using JSEncrypt to encrypt user's password on the client and send to server to decrypt.
I get the public key from the server which I build the RSA Key on the client with Javascript:

```
var leafCert = new X509();
leafCert.readCertPEM(publicCertificate);
```

In my encrypt method

```
var encryptKey = new JSEncrypt();
var encryptedValue = serverPublicKey.encrypt(inputStr)
return String(inputStr)
```

On server when I decrypt I see junk message. My server-side code:

```
public String decryptString(String encryptedVal, String sessionId)
{

    String sResult="";
    try
    {

        PrivateKey pvtKey = getPrivateKeyFromSession(sessionId);
        Cipher pkCipher=null;

        pkCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/None/NoPadding", "BC");
        pkCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, pvtKey);
        Base64 encoder = Base64.getInstance();          
        byte[] decodedValue = encoder.decode(encryptedVal);
        byte[] deCryptedBytes =pkCipher.doFinal( decodedValue );
        sResult = new String(deCryptedBytes);
    }           
    catch(Exception ex){log.error("Error decryptString" + ex.getMessage()); }
    return sResult.trim();
}
```

Can you let me know where am I going wrong. I do not see the actual decrypted message on the server.

Comment: What API are you using on the server side to decrypt?  Based on the code above you never use `encryptKey`.  In the server code do you need to do a `pkCipher.decrypt()` before performing 'pkCipher.doFinal()`?

Comment: Please see my server side code to decrypt in my question. The encrypt API stated in my question is on my client code as part of java script method. I cant change the server side implementation as its used by other various client applications. But I can modify my java script code to encrypt. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Ok, you still didn't address not using `encryptKey` during encryption.  Can you post a more complete client-side code?

Comment: Thanks, I have modified my client code to encrypt with public key as:                                          var rsa = new RSAKey();
rsa.setPublic(serverPublicKey.n,serverPublicKey.e);
var encryptedValue = rsa.encrypt(inputStr);           return encryptedValue;

Comment: But still unable to decrypt on server side. I guess the encrypt method of RSA by default considers padding.

Comment: I am facing this exact problem.. @Prashant B S did you find a solution? its been 4 years. Can you please share the answer if you found any?